# Phillips-Sarnak conjecture in higher dimension

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, automorphic-forms

The Phillips-Sarnak conjecture states that for a generic Fuchsian lattice the space of Maass cusp forms is finite-dimensional. Generic here means in particular non-uniform, non-arithmetic, no special symmetries.

When it comes to higher dimensional hyperbolic spaces then the isometry group still contains non-uniform, non-arithmetic lattices. Therefore I wonder what is known or expected about the existence or non-existence of Maass cusp forms for these lattices. For example, is there is an analogon of the Phillips-Sarnak conjecture?

Comment: What about superrigidity? Does it not contradict your claim about existence of non-arithmetic lattices in higher rank? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superrigidity

Comment: Hyperbolic spaces, also higher dimensional ones, are rank one spaces.